# "Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE" when importing database

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I have a dev server and a live server. I am just trying to update the dev server database with the live server database, so on the live server, I created a dump, and am just trying to import that into the dev database using:

```
mysql -uusername -p db < db.sql
```

But I receive the following error:

```
ERROR 1210 (HY000) at line 21: Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE
```

I've done this many times on other servers, but currently trying to do this on Google Cloud, and this is the first time I have seen the above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Any web plateform will not allow anonymous IP to access database from desktop application. Like in cPanel also we have to give our IP address generally static IP in order allow desktop application to access web database.

Answer (score 0):

As per [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#mysqldump), the SQL dump file must be created in an appropriate way for Cloud SQL usage: it cannot contain triggers, views, nor stored procedures.